# What is wrong with my one-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I have 2 models that have a 1 to many relationship with each other. There is one `Debate` for many `Arguments`.

My Debate is defined as:

```
class Debate(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "debates"

    title = db.Column(
        db.String(1000),
        nullable=False
        )
    description = db.Column(
        db.String(10000),
        nullable=True
    )
    creator_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("users.id"),
        nullable=False
        )
    community_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("communities.id"),
        nullable=False
        )
    arguments = db.relationship(
        "Argument",
        backref="debates"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Debate: {0}>".format(self.title)
```

My Argument is defined as:

```
class Argument(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "arguments"

    title = db.Column(
        db.String(1000),
        nullable=False
        )
    content = db.Column(
        db.String(1000000),
        nullable=False
        )
    user_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('users.id'),
        nullable=False
        )
    debate_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('debates.id'),
        nullable=False
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Argument: {0}>".format(self.title)
```

I don't get any actual error. When I try to migrate my application using flask-migrate it says `No changes in schema detected` even when I have changed the relationship(I don't know if that's normal). I have deleted my migrations directory and retried with the same result. When I select my Debate from the DB it simply comes back with no Arguments values.

I've been trying all sorts of different configurations and setups, and I've been reading the documentation and I just can't see what's wrong with this setup. I'm sure it's something small that I'm missing. Could you please let me know what is wrong with my definition?

Comment: What is wrong with it? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Sorry, I added the description of the error in.

Comment: "even when I have changed the relationship(I don't know if that's normal)" it is normal. Relationship works on the object side of the Object-Relational Mapping, so a change to it does not require any changes in the database. Please produce a [mcve] that includes examples of how you're adding and querying the data.

Comment: @IljaEverilä while trying to create a reproducible example, I ended up stumbling across the issue. I used flask_marshmallow to do my marshalling for me, and had an old name for my `arguments` value to this view. Previously they were called `posts`.